# Developer Story - missing tags in "personal tech stack"?

Tags: support, tags, developer-story

I just noticed the Developer Story tab and was trying to setup my profile there out of curiosity, but I'm already stuck at the first step.

The first thing is about filling the "Personal tech stack". My thought was that this is equivalent to SO tags, and I could just enter the tags where I've had most activity. But obviously this is not the case, because I'm unable to enter the tag where I've had most activity ([hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hadoop)).

See below for an example of what is being proposed to me when I type `hadoop` in the box. None of these are actually the [hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hadoop) tag. If I just press space to consider it a new tag, it just gets erased. There is `hadoop2`, but it has very low activity so not sure why it's being chosen over `hadoop`.

[image: Missing hadoop tag]

The interesting part is that if I try to enter a tag which for some reason doesn't bring anything in the list, I can then press space and then it will be accepted and not erased. For example, if I enter `apache-hadoop` it doesn't show anything matching in the list, and I can press space to have it accepted.

[image: Apache Hadoop tag]

So, this issue seems to be only happening in cases you try to enter a tag which brings at least 1 entry in the list.

Am I doing something really wrong and not understanding how I'm supposed to enter tags here, or is this a bug? It's also unclear how it chose to pre-populate a few tags initially yet omitting the ones where I've had most activity.